# Entity Framework hacking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have entity named DocumentItem. It has a natural key that consists of two columns : DocumentId (id of the document) and Index (the position of an item on a document).

This is a natural key so it has to change sometimes. Entity Framework prevents changes to the key. However I've managed to bind Inserts/Updates/Deletes to stored procedures. They get one extra parameter - NexIndex which becomes a new index for a DocumentItem when the sproc is executed.

There's however one problem: managing the object state manager so it has the current and valid information. Imagine a situation like this:

Document with document items:

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.

User deletes number 3 and adds a new position (always at the end, user cannot reorder items).

Changelist:
Delete 3 (ok)
Update 4 -> 3 (ok)
Update 5 -> 4 (ok)
Insert 5 - this is where it breaks

The problem is that Entity Framework is not aware of index changes. I've tried to bind Index back from database, but it always results in an exception "Cannot determine valid order of operations...".

Now the situation is as follows: EF believes that it already has item with index 5 so the last insert breaks.

I need to do something to clear the object state of the updated items so that I can add new or attach or download them from the db.
What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you make your Id the primary key instead of the composite key with all the hacking?

Comment: No, because it's not my decision. Besides I agree that this is the correct way to do it. I hate the idea that bad and poor tools should influence the design.

Comment: I don't agree that changing the order in which a document is displayed  should be a part of the primary key. It doesn't describe the documents identity.

Comment: It's not about a document but about it's positions/items. There can only be one position with number one, two, three,... and saying document no.215 position 1 clearly identifies document item.

Comment: But so does saying document no.215, surely? You can make the ordering field unique, but database keys conceptually are the object's absolute identity, and ordering information changes over time. Yet no matter where you display a document, it's still the same document.

Comment: This is a good point, but still it changes a little.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with database is pain in the ass generally. You can have your order column in the database but don't use it as a "real order" without gaps. If you delete item with order = 3 so be it. There will be a gap. When you insert new item add it with order = 6. Your items will be still ordered in correct order.

If you don't like this idea revert back to ADO.NET or don't use order as part of key.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET MVC website - correct indices come from the html form (javascript enriched) then they get checked by the controller(custom validation) and then comes the service layer which knows what operations should be done. What is more deleting/inserting is not equal here to updating an item because there's inventory management under the hood (FIFO/LIFO methods).

Comment: I've done some tests and I found out that simply detaching objects from an object context solves the problem.